# how to configure Postgres to work with pytest

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, pytest

I am using django for my backend and pytest to handle my tests.

I switched my project db from sqlite3 to postgres, everything works just fine except for the tests, for some reason all of my them are failing.

before switching I was able to access my db during my tests with the following line:

```
pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db
```

but now after using Postgres as my db I get this error on all of my tests

```
UndefinedTable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_marker' for <Function test_logged_user_saved_recipes_url_reverse>>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _django_db_marker(request):
        """Implement the django_db marker, internal to pytest-django.

        This will dynamically request the ``db``, ``transactional_db`` or
        ``django_db_reset_sequences`` fixtures as required by the django_db marker.   
        """
        marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("django_db")
        if marker:
            transaction, reset_sequences = validate_django_db(marker)
            if reset_sequences:
                request.getfixturevalue("django_db_reset_sequences")
            elif transaction:
                request.getfixturevalue("transactional_db")
            else:
>               request.getfixturevalue("db")
```

does anyone knows the right way to access Postgres db while using pytest?
or maybe there is a way to switch to sqlite3 db only when testing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so adding this code to conftest.py resolved the problem for me

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
}
```